# making non-shared copies of boost::interprocess shared memory objects

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I have implemented various classes that are designed to be used in `boost::interprocess` shared memory segments. All their constructors employ `allocator<void,segment_manager>` references—some explicitly in the definitions I have written (like the `Foo` constructor below) and some simply because that's what the boost container definition requires, in boost library code that I should not be changing (like the `IndexVector` below).

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>

typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory                   Segment;
typedef boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager  SegmentManager;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator< void, SegmentManager >       Allocator;

typedef size_t                                                       Index;
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator< Index, SegmentManager >      IndexAllocator;
typedef boost::interprocess::vector<    Index, IndexAllocator >      IndexVector;

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo( const Allocator & alloc ) : mData( alloc ) {}
       ~Foo() {}

    private:
        IndexVector mData;

};
```

Mostly, these objects sit in shared memory.  But I sometimes want to create copies of them in *non*-shared memory.  My question is this:  do I have to define a whole different class (e.g. `Foo_Nonshared`) containing different member types (`std::vector<Index>` instead of my shared `IndexVector` type) and provide copy/conversion functions between them? That will be a lot of work and a lot of stupid duplication.  I could reduce duplication by providing an alternative constructor to the existing `Foo` class,  but then I wouldn't know how to initialize the `IndexVector` member without an allocator.

Or is there some nice shortcut? I'm imagining some sort of particular `allocator` instance that I can pass to `Foo()`, and which will hence be passed on to the `IndexVector` constructor,  which will be recognized by both as meaning "allocate in non-shared memory".  Does such a thing exist? Is there a "dummy segment manager" for managing vanilla non-shared memory?    Or are there other ways around this problem?

I'm hoping for C++03-compatible answers even though I'm also interested to learn the C++11+ ways of doing things.

**Update** following question being marked as duplicate: I have read these previous similar questions:

- [boost::interprocess Containers of containers NOT in shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217012/boostinterprocess-containers-of-containers-not-in-shared-memory)
- [boost::interprocess Containers of containers NOT in shared memory copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711499/boostinterprocess-containers-of-containers-not-in-shared-memory-copy)

and have tried to generalize what I see there, with some successes and some failures (see listing below).  There are a few compiler errors that I haven't been able to resolve, marked ERROR—in particular I cannot figure out how to instantiate methods that iterate over the members of these highly "meta" containers. But with or without those errors, I cannot yet see how to make templates-of-templates into a maintainable solution (my objects, in reality, contain containers of other complex objects, which contain further containers, which AFAICS complicates the syntax beyond sanity...  see the part marked "hmm").

I guess, in the end, I might have to re-design to avoid having the same objects in shared and heap memory.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess; // warning: C++11 alias declaration

template <typename T, template<typename...> class Allocator>  // warning: C++11 variadic template
    using Vector = bip::vector< T, Allocator<T>>;             // warning: C++11 alias declaration
// this seems to work to get some of the nested <>ness under control.
// But I can't figure out how to create an iterator to this kind of type (see errors below)

// what once were classes are now class templates

template <template<typename...> class Allocator>              // warning: C++11 variadic template
    class Bar
    {
        public:
             Bar( const Allocator<void> & alloc ) : mInts( alloc ) {}
            ~Bar() {}

            void Report( void );

        private:
            Vector< int, Allocator > mInts;
    };

template <template<typename...> class Allocator>              // warning: C++11 variadic template
    class Foo
    {
        public:
             Foo( const Allocator<void> & alloc ) : mBars( alloc ) {}
            ~Foo() {}

            void Report( void );


        private:
            Vector<  Bar<Allocator>, Allocator >  mBars; // hmm, with more complex structures this is going 
                                                         // to get unmanageably< nested< very< quickly > > > ...

    };


// Define allocator templates

template <typename T>
    using HeapAllocator  = std::allocator<T>; // warning: C++11 alias declaration

template <typename T> 
    using ShmemAllocator = bip::allocator<T, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>; // warning: C++11 alias declaration

// Define two class variants: one for use on the heap and one for use in shared memory

using HeapFoo  = Foo< HeapAllocator  >; // warning: C++11 alias declaration
using ShmemFoo = Foo< ShmemAllocator >; // warning: C++11 alias declaration

// Try to define methods (unsuccessful so far because of the iterators,
// but they compile OK if the function bodies are left empty):

template <template<typename...> class Allocator>              // warning: C++11 variadic template
    void
    Bar< Allocator >::Report( void )
    {
        std::cout << "[";
        Vector< int, Allocator >::iterator it;
// ERROR:     ^~~~~ expected ';' after expression
        for( it = mInts.begin(); it += mInts.end(); it++ )
            std::cout << ( it == mInts.begin() ? "" : ", " ) << *it;
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

template <template<typename...> class Allocator>              // warning: C++11 variadic template
    void
    Foo< Allocator >::Report( void )
    {
        Vector< Bar< Allocator >, Allocator >::iterator it;
// ERROR:     ^~~~~ expected ';' after expression
        for( it = mBars.begin(); it += mBars.end(); it++ )
            it->Report();
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

int main( void )
{
    struct shm_remove
    {
         shm_remove() { bip::shared_memory_object::remove( "MySharedMemory" ); }
        ~shm_remove() { bip::shared_memory_object::remove( "MySharedMemory" ); }
    } remover;
    bip::managed_shared_memory   seg( bip::create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536 );

    ShmemAllocator< void > shalloc( seg.get_segment_manager() );
    HeapAllocator<  void > halloc;

    HeapFoo  foo1( halloc  );
    ShmemFoo foo2( shalloc );
    foo1.Report();
    foo2.Report();  
}
```

Comment: see also the [followup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711499/boostinterprocess-containers-of-containers-not-in-shared-memory-copy) to the dupe question for relevant ideas

Comment: Hmm, yes I had seen those threads. I understand the language/concepts of your answers to the first one but struggle with the follow-up, especially the OP's comment and answer to it ("deduce the arguments in a function template, and dispatch to a function object which you specialize for different actual argument types" is entirely beyond my level of understanding).  In the first one, it seems like the work has to be done by hand and on foot,  copying member-by-member: this is what I was hoping to avoid with a "dummy" segment manager (but I guess no such thing exists).

Comment: In the second thread, it seems like the solution is very specific to container classes (i.e. those that implement `assign`, `begin` and `end`).  I guess I need to implement assignment specific methods that do the work of converting between my `Foo<Allocator>` and `Foo<std::allocator>`.

Comment: I spoke too soon about understanding the first thread. "templatized for an Allocator class template" and `template <template<typename...> class Allocator>` are going to require some research before I can get what's going on here.

Comment: Reopened:  for more-complex classes, can't even get as far as the copy operation.

Comment: Okay :) The added code made it clear what exactly you were stuck with. I hope my answer helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you've run into the Frequently Annoying Edgecase that template-template arguments aren't first class citizens in C++ (you cannot pass them around/typedef them):

- [How to transmit a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108614/how-to-transmit-a-template/27109422#27109422)

What shall we do?

1. **`allocator::rebind<T>`**

   Allocators have a rebind mechanism, I daresay precisely because of this. So you can pass a `alloc<void>` as if it is the open template, because you can always get from there to a sibling allocator type by doing `Alloc::rebind<T>::other`.
2. Add to this the fact that allocators usually have conversion constructors that do this rebinding, you don't need to be overly specific in many places taking allocators
3. in c++11, `scoped_allocator`s have been introduced to avoid having to manually pass `allocator` instances in a number of places that will do internal construction of elements (e.g. `emplace_back`).

   There's library magic in place that will automatically add the allocator instance from the container's `scoped_allocator` as the last constructor argument (by default). Boost Container library has backported the `scoped_allocator_adaptor` concept to c++03 so you can use it.

Here's a full sample that shows you how to solve the issues you had, and also, how you can mix the heap-based `Bar` instances with the shared-memory `Foo` instance:

```
foo2.add(bar1); // this works because of ... MAGIC!
```

Which works due to the `scoped_allocator` mentioned above.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09ba909a66518025)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

namespace generic { 

    template <typename T, typename Alloc/* = std::allocator<T>*/ >
        using vector = bip::vector<T, typename Alloc::template rebind<T>::other >;

    template <typename Alloc> struct Bar {
        typedef Alloc allocator_type; // ties in with uses_allocator/scoped_allocator

        // only require allocator if not default-constructible
        Bar(Alloc alloc = Alloc()) : mInts(alloc) {}

        // conversion constructor so we can convert between allocators 
        template <typename OtherAlloc>
            Bar(Bar<OtherAlloc> const& rhs, Alloc alloc = Alloc())
                : mInts(rhs.mInts.begin(), rhs.mInts.end(), alloc) 
            {
            }

        void Report() const;

        void add(int i) { mInts.emplace_back(i); }

      private:
        template<typename OtherAlloc> friend struct Bar; // we can see each other's mInts
        typedef vector<int, Alloc> ints_t;
        ints_t mInts;
    };

    template <typename Alloc> struct Foo {
        typedef Alloc allocator_type; // ties in with uses_allocator/scoped_allocator

        Foo(Alloc alloc = Alloc()) : mBars(alloc) {}
        void Report() const;

        template <typename Bar>
        void add(Bar const& bar) { mBars.emplace_back(bar); }

      private:
        typedef vector<Bar<Alloc>, Alloc> mbars_t;
        mbars_t mBars;
    };
}

namespace heap {
    using VAlloc = std::allocator<void>;

    using Bar = generic::Bar<VAlloc>;
    using Foo = generic::Foo<VAlloc>;
}

namespace shared {
    using VAlloc = boost::container::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<void, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> >;

    using Bar = generic::Bar<VAlloc>;
    using Foo = generic::Foo<VAlloc>;
}

template <typename Alloc> void generic::Bar<Alloc>::Report() const {
    std::cout << "[";
    for (typename ints_t::const_iterator it = mInts.begin(); it != mInts.end(); it++)
        std::cout << (it == mInts.begin() ? "" : ", ") << *it;
    std::cout << "]\n";
}

template <typename Alloc>
void generic::Foo<Alloc>::Report() const {
    for (typename mbars_t::const_iterator it = mBars.begin(); it != mBars.end(); it++)
        it->Report();
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main(void) {
    struct shm_remove {
        shm_remove()  { bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
        ~shm_remove() { bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
    } remover;

    ///////////////////////////////////
    // heap based:
    std::cout << "Heap based storage: \n";

    heap::Foo foo1;
    heap::Bar bar1;

    bar1.add(42);
    bar1.add(2);
    bar1.add(-99);

    foo1.add(bar1);
    foo1.Report();

    /////////////////////////////////
    std::cout << "Shared memory storage: \n";
    bip::managed_shared_memory seg(bip::create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);
    shared::VAlloc shalloc(seg.get_segment_manager());

    shared::Foo foo2(shalloc);
    shared::Bar bar2(shalloc);

    bar2.add(43);
    bar2.add(3);
    bar2.add(-98);

    foo2.add(bar2); // of course this works
    foo2.add(bar1); // this works because of ... MAGIC!
    foo2.Report();
}
```

Prints:

```
Heap based storage: 
[42, 2, -99]

Shared memory storage: 
[43, 3, -98]
[42, 2, -99]
```